# How can we test plain Java code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

If I have a project in Eclipse, I can at any time create a class with a `main` and test anything *having* all the classes and libraries of my project available.

How do I do something like that in Android Studio?

If I have a big project and I would like to test a small method in isolation, how would I do that without needing to run the emulator or an Activity, etc?

Answer (score 3):

To create a run/debug configuration for a class or method in your Java code, follow these steps:

1. Open a project in Android or Project view.
2. Open a Java file in the Code Editor.
3. Select a class or method in the code, and then press Ctrl+Shift+T (⌘⇧T).
4. Select Create New Test from the menu that appears.
5. In the Create Test dialog, optionally change the field values, and then click OK.
6. In the Choose Destination Directory dialog, select androidTest to create an instrumented test or test to create a local unit test. Click OK.

The new test appears in the Project window in the corresponding test source set.

7. To run the test, do one of the following:

   - In the Project window, right-click the test and select Run or Debug.
   - In the Code Editor, right-click a class definition in the test file and select Run or Debug to test all methods in the class.
   - In the Code Editor, right-click a method name in the test file and select Run or Debug to test just that method.
   - In the Code Editor, click Play  in the left margin next to a class or method and select Run or Debug.
8. To save the configuration, select Save from the Select Run/Debug Configuration drop-down list within the toolbar.
   The drop-down list is to the left of Run  and Debug  ; for example, .

Alternatively, right-click the item again and select Save.

Or, select the configuration in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog and click Save Configuration  on the upper lef

**[SOURCE](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on your class and select `Run YourClassName.main()`

Answer (score 1):

If The Class you are using only use plain old Java no `android.*` You can make a Run Configuration just like you would do in Eclipse. Otherwise You need to Write `JUnit tests` and run them on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have a separate small, pure Java module that's mostly for that purpose and is included more or less as a library in my app. I also toss JUnit there for those classes I need to test, and Gradle executes those when the app is built.

Not sure if that applies to your scenario, as I am not sure what types of things you are testing - Java methods or Android libraries, but from what you describe, what is preventing you from running a Java class with a main method on its own? You'd right-click a class in Eclipse and select the Run option there. That also exists in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your class file by clicking CTRL+SHIFT+F10